# Database modeling for products and store

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, django

I am planning to develop a virtual shopping mall where stores of any kind can be registered, such as in a physical shopping mall. First I want to develop an efficient and effective database modeling for products and stores only. I wanted it be very flexible and user friendly. Here is the model design for `Product` and `Store`. How can I improve the database design?

My concern is mainly for the categories be user friendly. For example `Men -> Clothing -> Shirts` as a category. If you wish, you can help me to improve the design as well, I would appreciate all recommendations.

I am using Python 3 and Django 1.11.

```
DAY = (( 'Sun', 'Sunday'),
       ( 'Mon', 'Monday'),
       ( 'Tue', 'Tuesday'),
       ( 'Wed', 'Wednesday'),
       ( 'Thu', 'Thursday'),
       ( 'Fri', 'Friday'),
       ( 'Sat', 'Saturday')
    )

class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey('Store', related_name="opening_hour")
    weekday = models.CharField(choices=DAY, max_length=12)
    opening_hour = models.TimeField()
    closing_hour = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Opening Hour'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Opening Hours'

    def ___str__(self):
        return '{} {} - {}'.format(self.weekday, str(self.opening_hour), str(self.closing_hour))

class Store(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=False)
    token = models.CharField(default=token_generator, max_length=20, unique=True, editable=False)
    name_of_legal_entity = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    registered_office_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_of_store = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, null=False)
    store_contact_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    # store_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True)
    # store_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=8, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Store'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_of_store

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Store'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Stores'

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    token = models.CharField(default=token_generator, max_length=20, unique=True, editable=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey('CatalogCategory', related_name='products')
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name="product_brand")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
    name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False,null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_gurantee_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_negotiated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_instock = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_of_product

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'


class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/brand/images/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Brand'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Brands'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Variation(models.Model):
    VAR_CATEGORIES = (
        ('size', 'size'),
        ('color', 'color'),
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    token = models.CharField(default=token_generator, max_length=20, unique=True, editable=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    discount = models.DecimalField(blank=True ,null =True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(blank=True ,null =True, decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Variation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Variations'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} of {1} from {2}' .format(self.product.name_of_product, self.title, self.product.store.name_of_store)


class CatalogCategory(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(default=token_generator, max_length=20, unique=True, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'CatalogCategory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'CatalogCategories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, blank=True, related_name="product_image")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/images/')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    @property
    def imageName(self):
        return str(os.path.basename(self.image.name))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Images'


class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    STORE_CATEGORIES= (
        ('GROCERY', ('Grocery')),
        ('MEATS', ('Meats')),
        ('FOODS & BEVERAGES', ('Foods')),
        ('COMPUTERS', ('Computers')),
        ('ELECTRONICS', ('Electronics')),
        ('HOME & OUTDOOR', ('Home & Outdoor')),
        ('FASHION & BEAUTY', ('Fashion & Beauty')),
        ('HEALTH', ('Health')),
        ('SPORTS & FITNESS', ('Sports & Fitness')),
        ('BABY', ('Baby')),
        ('BOOKS', ('Books')),
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store_category = models.CharField(choices=STORE_CATEGORIES, default='GROCERY', max_length=30)
    # objects = VariationManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Store Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Store Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        # return str(self.product.name_of_product)
        return '{0} of category {1}' .format(self.product.name_of_product, str(self.store_category))
```

Answer (score 1):

The models look about right.

```
def imageName(self):
```

Well, ok, [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you spell this `image_name`, but,
whatever, I'm sure you had other constraints you were working within.

In `STORE_CATEGORIES` I don't understand why `Foods` is special.
It otherwise has [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) issues that could be addressed
by applying `.upper()` or `.title()` to a single copy of the list.

Looks good to me. Ship it!